# Spring, restTemplate retries on http 503 response, even when I have no retry mechanism

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, resttemplate

I'm doing the simplest of the requests possible with rest template:

```
  restTemplate.execute(myUriUrl, HttpMethod.GET, myRequestCallback, myResponseExtractor);
```

I don't want any retries. However, when the server returns http 503, the template retries one more time. As I use my own http server, I can easily see there are two requests coming rather than one. But this only happens when the server is configured to return http 503. For any other 5xx http response, the restTemplate doesn't retry.

How can I disable retries completely? This didn't happen with older versions of Spring. Now I'm using Java 17 with Spring 6.0.7 and Spring Boot 3.0.5

Comment: As far as I know, `RestTemplate` does not automatically retry a request that receives a 503 response. Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example of the behavior that you have described?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for pointing me to RestTemplate as the culprit for my RestController being invoked a second time.

RestTemplate appears to use Apache HttpClient (if available) for the actual call. And the retry on a 503 response is a default strategy (See [DefaultHttpRequestRetryStrategy](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.1.x/current/httpclient5/apidocs/org/apache/hc/client5/http/impl/DefaultHttpRequestRetryStrategy.html)):

> Create the HTTP request retry strategy with a max retry count of 1, default retry interval of 1 second, and using the following list of non-retriable I/O exception classes:
> InterruptedIOException UnknownHostException ConnectException ConnectionClosedException SSLException and retriable HTTP status codes:
> SC_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS (429) **SC_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE (503)**

By default, RestTemplateBuilder builds a RequestFactory with `ClientHttpRequestFactories.get(this.requestFactorySettings)`.
The requestFactorySettings only contains 3 settings and no possibility to  configure or disable automatic retries.

In the end I solved it this way:

```
@Configuration
public class TestRestTemplateConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate testRestTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .errorHandler(new RestTemplateResponseErrorHandler())
                .requestFactory(() -> new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(HttpClients.custom()
                        .disableAutomaticRetries()
                        .useSystemProperties()
                        .build()))
                .build();
    }
}
```